# C++ basic string input and output

Tags: c++

Alright, so I've got a simple online programming assignment that's checked by an automatic grading thingy. Most have been pretty easy, but I can't get this assignment to work. Here's the prompt and my code. I have a feeling I'm missing something fairly simple. Thanks for your help.

> Students just took a short, two question, multiple choice quiz. Both questions needed to >be answered correctly to receive credit. As their grader, you must determine whether >students got credit or not. The correct answers were A and D.
>
> Input
>
> The students' answers, sepated by a space.
>
> Output
>
> "Credit" or "No credit"
>
> Example
>
> Input:
> A C
>
> Output:
> No credit

---

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input;
    cin >> input;
    if (input == "A D")
    {
        cout << "Credit";
    }    
    else 
    {
        cout << "No credit";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use a string compare function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::cin` will stop searching for input when it hits a new line `\n` or whitespace. In order to get the entire line of input, use `std::getline`:

```
std::string input;
std::getline(std::cin, input);
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew I was missing something simple but couldn't figure out what it was.